# Can't Load Composer Package

Tags: php, package, composer-php, httpful

I'm new to using composer packages. I've gotten a few to work, but I came across a Google Maps package I'd like to use and I can't get it to load properly.

[php-google-maps package](https://packagist.org/packages/php-google-maps/php-google-maps)

My attempt at using the package:

```
<?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

use \PHPGoogleMaps\Service\Geocoder;
use \PHPGoogleMaps\Service\GeocodeError;
use \PHPGoogleMaps\Service\GeocodeResult;
use \PHPGoogleMaps\Service\GeocodeException;

$map = new \PHPGoogleMaps\Map;
// Rest of GMap code goes here...
?>
```

This fails with the message `Class 'PHPGoogleMaps\Map' not found`

composer.json File:

```
{
    "require" : {
        "nategood/httpful":"*",
        "nesbot/carbon": "dev-master",
        "php-google-maps/php-google-maps": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the content of `composer.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the composer.json for PHPGoogleMaps package. Directory structure after the installation doesn't follow PSR-0 autoloading standard.

I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/galen/PHPGoogleMaps/pull/16) fixing the problem but until it's fixed you can define your own repository for the package (changing the target-dir):

```
{
    "require" : {
        "nategood/httpful":"*",
        "nesbot/carbon": "dev-master",
        "jakzal/php-google-maps": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jakzal/php-google-maps",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/galen/PHPGoogleMaps",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-0": {"PHPGoogleMaps": ""}
                },
                "target-dir": "PHPGoogleMaps"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```